# Docusign Connect - HMAC validation example

Tags: docusignconnect

Is there an example implementation of validating HMAC in .NET Core 5 WebApi? I've been following the guidance from here https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/hmac/
but signatures never seem to match in my application